# Managing Oracle BFILES

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently working on a solution to write/read BFile from a java application to Oracle Database. I've searched information about BFile manipulation and it seems that the only way is the call of remote pl sql procedures.

I'm working with Spring Framework, and it seems that there is no way to manage Oracle BFile from Hibernate or Spring JPA, anybody can advice me about that? What is the better way to manage this data type? I think that I will use Oracle jdbc driver directly and I will call procedures and functions from it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "write BFile from Java to DB". BFile is a pointer to a regular file on a filesystem of the OS your Oracle DB has access to. So, if you want to manage BFiles from Java,...

**Prerequisites**

1. Ask your DBA to create a "directory" DB object pointing to an OS folder of your choice, let's call it DIR_MY_FILES for purposes of this answer.
2. Ask your DBA to grant "read on directory DIR_MY_FILES" to your DB user.

**Actions**

1. Copy your file MY_FILE.DAT to the OS folder of your choice.
2. Create a BFile variable in PL/SQL or insert a row into a table with a BFile-type column with the value of BFILENAME('DIR_MY_FILES', 'MY_FILE.DAT').

There, you're all set. Now you can read the files mostly like any other LOB data type.